# What is the difference between granulation and supergranulation in the Sun's photosphere?

Tags: astrophysics, plasma-physics, sun

Granulation and super granulation seem to be some sort confused topics as they are due to the heated particles coming out of the surface. What is the difference between the two?

Answer (score 2):

Granules in the photosphere are caused because there are convection currents of plasma.

The grainy appearance of the photosphere is caused by the top of these convective cells and is called granulation.

The granules are 1500Kms and last 20 minutes.

Supergranules are much bigger, 30000kms and last 24 hours.

Now because of the structure of these, supergranules are the ones that get fragmented at their uppermost layers into granules.

So granulation and supergranulation is the same thing, but supergranules get created first, and get fragmented into granules.